# Windows Metro Apps Minimize themselves when Launched

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

After installing the Microsoft January 2015 Patch Tuesday updates for Windows 8.1 Pro x64, I have noticed some strange behavior with my computer. For one thing, my task tray icons, which I am OCD about having in a particular order, have been rearranged, and rearranging back to the way I like them does not keep the settings after I restart or shut down. The second problem is that I am unable to open any Windows Metro app. Whenever I launch the app, the splash screen will appear and the app will immediately minimize itself and attempting to reopen the app window leads to it minimizing again. Below is a poor-quality GIF demonstrating the problem with the Windows Store, although this is an issue with every metro app I have installed on my computer.

[image: Windows Store Crashes]

Additionaly, the following Metro Apps are missing their icons:

- Adobe Photoshop Express
- Calendar
- Calendar Tiles
- Food & Drink
- Games
- Help + Tips
- Mail
- Maps
- Minesweeper 3D
- Money
- Music
- News
- People
- Skype
- Sound Recorder
- Sports
- TeamViewer Touch
- Travel
- Video
- VLC
- Weather

I have tried using the [Windows Store Apps Troubleshooter](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20291-windows-store-apps-troubleshooter-fix-apps-windows-8-a.html) to resolve the problem, and it does resolve the problem until I shut down or reboot, at which point the problem returns again. I have also tried resolving the problem using `sfc /scannow`, but this also did not warrant any results.

**Update: I have found that if I restart the Explorer program in Task Manager, my task tray icons are organized the way I want them to be, and Metro apps work just fine. What is causing this?**

Comment: Feel like I'm saying this to 90% of posts about windows issues now, but... Have you tried to system restore to a restore point short before the patch?

Comment: @SadBunny Yes I did, but I forgot to mention it in the post.

Comment: How about uninstalling the patch and/or related updates? (From Control Panel - Programs and Features - View Installed Updates.)

Comment: @SadBunny I have not tried that.

Comment: I say try it :) You can always reinstall them again later. Two options: Option 1 - problem goes away after removing updates. Means it's in the updates. After that you reinstall half of them, then see if the problem comes back. That way you cut the number of possible problematic updates in half. Repeat until you sift out where the problem lies. Then google that KB number.
OPTION 2 - problem stays. Then it's not in the updates.

Comment: @SadBunny I have determined that the problem occurs only when update KB3021674 is installed.

Comment: Ok, you pinpointed the problem, good! A quick Google shows that you're not the only one, though it's not like there's thousands of people with the same trouble. It may be a conflict with some other stuff you're using or settings that you have done.
Have you disabled UAC and/or use Directory Opus? See http://resource.dopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23788
See https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS15-003 for a read on what this update is for. Seems to be a nasty exploit that Google publicly disclosed after MS failed to fix it in time after their initial report. Maybe contact MS Support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found solution and it worked for me.

1. Open Registry Editor using regedit.exe.
2. Right click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
3. Click on "Permissions" and in popup click on "Add".
4. In 2nd Popup click on "Advanced".
5. In 3rd Popus click on "Find Now".
6. In "Search Results" click on "All Application Packages" and then click "Ok".
7. Now in 2nd Popup "Select Users or Groups" click again "Ok".
8. In Permissions select under Allow "Read" and Click "Ok".
9. Close the Registry Editor. No need to restart.

Metro apps works again and never more minimize!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, although I was able to resolve the problem by recreating my user account. Do you have any idea why your suggestion works?

Comment: I have no idea what happened in system registry, but I think that it is something in common with the installation of Corel Draw. This solution I have found after reading many articles about metro apps minimizing and only this solutions working for me. Recreating user account not helped me.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the exact problem here. and I solved it by:

1. Boot to Windows Recovery Environment (RE), reach to command prompt.
2. Get Windows 8.1 drive letter by running:

   ```
   diskpart
   lis vol
   exit
   ```
3. Suppose the drive letter was E:

   ```
   icacls E:\* /T /C /Q /L /RESET
   ```
4. Reboot to Windows 8.1 again and also form an elevated command prompt (for localized windows versions, change "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" to match your language (in spanish: "TODOS LOS PAQUETES DE APLICACIONES"):

   ```
   icacls "C:\Program Files" /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(OI)(CI)(RX) /C /Q
   icacls C:\Windows /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(OI)(CI)(RX) /C /Q
   icacls C:\users /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(OI)(CI)(F) /C /Q
   ```

Step 4 is automated based on [a Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2798317).